# Found one big issue with Google payments center help. Something completely illogical happening there

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, mobile-application

I was trying to purchase a google play console but facing an issue with the Google Payments center, I was not able to update or add my card there because of some error.

I contacted the google pay team for some reason and they said you have to talk with the payments team which is logical. After finding out the contact page **on the payments center I notice that they are asking for Merchant ID, now the thing is how I am gonna get the Merchant ID of that developer console which I didn't even purchase yet? and I need Merchant ID to contact the payments team so basically there is no way to contact the payments team to resolve this issue**. I didn't understand why this completely illogical thing is exist on Google

Screenshot included -[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue right now. Seems extremely fishy that they let you add payments but provide no way to remove them.